# SQL select specific letter from concatenated string

Tags: sql, string, oracle, concatenation

This may have been answered similarly somewhere but I am still kind of confused. I need to create a view named A7T7 that will display the concatenated first name and last name of the students who have at least three letter Os or three letter Ts in their concatenated name (e.g., John Olson, Richard Hooton, Tina Trout). The column heading should be Student and the rows should be sorted by the length of the concatenated names from long to short.

Not really sure how to make my WHERE statement for this restriction.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `LIKE` query - for example (using a table variable for SQL Server):

```
CREATE TABLE #students (firstname varchar(20), lastname varchar(20));

INSERT ALL
  INTO #students VALUES ('John','Olson')
  INTO #students VALUES ('Richard','Hooton')
  INTO #students VALUES ('Tina','Trout')
SELECT 1 FROM dual;     

SELECT *
FROM #students s
WHERE CONCAT(s.firstname, s.lastname) LIKE '%o%o%o%';

DROP TABLE #students;
```

Which roughly translates to "select all the rows from students where the concatenation of firstname and lastname contains `o` three times".

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause will work correctly in any RDBMS I think (not counting Access :-) ).

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis - It won't in Oracle (which by looking at OP's last question is the database). `Concat()` is more like it.

Comment: Thank you! Figured it out appreciate the help guys